# NoSuchMethod Error: Closure call with missmatched arguments : Function '_FilterScreenState.build'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an Android Meals APP using flutter,in order to filter meals in a (filters_screen.dart ) file, I've created a builder method (_buildSwitchListTile) to return a group of SwitchListTile widget to reuse it for many bool condition, as shown in the code below :

```
 Widget _buildSwitchListTile(
    String title,
    String description,
     bool currentValue,
    Function updateValue,
   ){
        return SwitchListTile(
          title: Text(title),
          value: currentValue,
          subtitle: Text(
           description
            ),
           onChanged: updateValue(),
           );
  }
```

after that, I recall the builder method in Expanded Widget as shown bellow:

```
  Expanded(
           child: ListView(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   _buildSwitchListTile(
                     'Gluten-free',
                      'Only include Gluten-free meals',
                       _glutenFree,
                      (newValue){
                             setState(() {
                               _glutenFree =  newValue;
                             });
                      }
                      ),
                              _buildSwitchListTile(
                     'Lactose-free',
                      'Only include lactose-free meals',
                       _lactoseFree,
                      (newValue){
                             setState(() {
                               _lactoseFree =  newValue;
                             });
                      }
                      ),
                                 _buildSwitchListTile(
                     'Vegetarian',
                      'Only include Vegetarian meals',
                       _lactoseFree,
                      (newValue){
                             setState(() {
                               _vegetarian =  newValue;
                             });
                      }
                      ),
                                   _buildSwitchListTile(
                     'Vegan',
                      'Only include Vegan meals',
                       _lactoseFree,
                      (newValue){
                             setState(() {
                               _vegan =  newValue;
                             }
                             );
                      }
                      ),
                 ],
         ),
         ),
```

everything is okay in the code but my app keep crashing,
I'd appreciate your help.

My filters_screen.dart file :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals_app/widgets/main_drawer.dart';

class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 static const routeName = '/filters';


 @override
 State<FiltersScreen> createState() => _FiltersScreenState();
}

class _FiltersScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
 bool _glutenFree = false;
 bool _vegetarian = false;
 bool _vegan = false;
 bool _lactoseFree =  false;

 Widget _buildSwitchListTile(
   String title,
   String description,
    bool currentValue,
   Function updateValue,
  ){
       return SwitchListTile(
         title: Text(title),
         value: currentValue,
         subtitle: Text(
          description
           ),
          onChanged: updateValue(),
          );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Your Filters'),
     ),
    drawer: MainDrawer(),
     body: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
       Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
         child: Text('Adjust your meal selection', 
         style:TextStyle(
           fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
           fontSize: 24,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
         ),
         ),
       ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildSwitchListTile(
                    'Gluten-free',
                     'Only include Gluten-free meals',
                      _glutenFree,
                     (newValue){
                            setState(() {
                              _glutenFree =  newValue;
                            });
                     }
                     ),
                             _buildSwitchListTile(
                    'Lactose-free',
                     'Only include lactose-free meals',
                      _lactoseFree,
                     (newValue){
                            setState(() {
                              _lactoseFree =  newValue;
                            });
                     }
                     ),
                                _buildSwitchListTile(
                    'Vegetarian',
                     'Only include Vegetarian meals',
                      _lactoseFree,
                     (newValue){
                            setState(() {
                              _vegetarian =  newValue;
                            });
                     }
                     ),
                                  _buildSwitchListTile(
                    'Vegan',
                     'Only include Vegan meals',
                      _lactoseFree,
                     (newValue){
                            setState(() {
                              _vegan =  newValue;
                            }
                            );
                     }
                     ),
                ],
        ),
        ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

ok, so the problem is the following:

```
Function updateValue;
...
onChanged: updateValue(),
```

So first of all, `updateValue`'s signature is `dynamic Function([dynamic])` while `onChanged`'s signature is `void Function(bool)`, which means you **can** use `updateValue` as an `onChanged` value, but if you use it wrong it will give you this error.

Second problem is: You are calling `updateValue`:

```
onChanged: updateValue(),
```

which means `onChanged` will be whatever `updateValue` returns instead of `updateValue` itself.

To fix this, you only need to remove the parenthesis after `updateValue`:

```
onChanged: updateValue,
```

Another possible fix is calling the new value with an anonymous closure:

```
onChanged: (val) => updateValue(val),
```

Comment: I already tried the first solution but it rised an error 'The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool)?'' , but the second solution has solved the problem, Thank you so much